# SQL Server Management Studio 2008 - why won't my left join provide null records?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull records from two tables, a master table, and a transaction table.

My `Master` table contains all of my account IDs. My `transaction` table has any transaction run by these accounts with 3 columns: `activity date`, `income`, and `charge type`.

In the `transaction` table, some of these accounts may not appear at all because they have not performed a transaction during a given date range. However, I still need these accounts to appear on my result list when I query them.

So my data would look like this:

```
     Master Table:                         Transaction Table:

    | AccountID  |              | AccountID | ChargeType | ActivityDate| Income |
    --------------              -------------------------------------------------
    |      1     |              |     2     |    2000    |  8/31/2012  | $99.00 |
    |      2     |              |     3     |    2000    |  7/31/2012  | $79.00 |
    |      3     |              |     5     |    2000    |  9/30/2012  | $79.00 |
    |      4     |
    |      5     |
```

My query currently looks like:

```
select
    a.AccountID,
    b.ChargeType,
    b.ActivityDate,
    b.Income
From
    MasterTable as A
left join
    TransactionTable as B on a.AccountID = b.AccountID
where
    a.AccountID in ('1','2','3','4','5')
    and
    b.ActivityDate between '5/1/2012' and '11/30/2012'
```

From what I understand, this query should list all 5 accounts I've chosen, and display `NULL` values for the accounts not found in the `TransactionTable`.

Results I expect:

```
        | AccountID | ChargeType | ActivityDate| Income |
        -------------------------------------------------
        |     1     |    NULL    |     NULL    |  NULL  |
        |     2     |    2000    |  8/31/2012  | $99.00 |
        |     3     |    2000    |  7/31/2012  | $79.00 |
        |     4     |    NULL    |     NULL    |  NULL  | 
        |     5     |    2000    |  9/30/2012  | $79.00 |
```

The incorrect results I receive instead:

```
         | AccountID | ChargeType | ActivityDate| Income |
         -------------------------------------------------
         |     2     |    2000    |  8/31/2012  | $99.00 |
         |     3     |    2000    |  7/31/2012  | $79.00 |
         |     5     |    2000    |  9/30/2012  | $79.00 |
```

I assume I am misunderstanding something fundamental here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you have the "b" table referenced in the `where` clause, so NULL values are filtered out.

Move the condition to the `on` clause:

```
From
    MasterTable A left join
    TransactionTable B
    on a.AccountID=b.AccountID and
       a.AccountID in ('1','2','3','4','5') and
       b.ActivityDate between '5/1/2012' and '11/30/2012'
```

Comment: Why move the `a.AccountID in ('1','2','3','4','5')` part to the `on` clause? Doesn't that piece still belong in the `where`? I know it won't affect the results, but semantically that piece of logic has no effect on the `join`

Comment: Selected as Best answer because Gordon described why the query was not working.  You can not reference the right table in the `where` clause.

Comment: @ean5533 . . . There is no right answer to whether the filtering logic on the left table should be in the `on` clause or the `where` clause.  Some think "filtering" logic should be in `where` and join logic in `on`.  But, the condition on table b seems like filtering to most people, and yet it still belongs in the `on` clause.  For me, I might be inclined to use `where b.ActivityDate between '2012-01-05' and '2012-11-30' or b.AccountId is NULL` because this explicitly handles the `left outer join`.  However, people learning SQL should learn the right way using the `on` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Change the last filter of your `WHERE` Clause to; [SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e46be/5)

```
DECLARE @d1 DATETIME, @d2 DATETIME
SELECT @d1 = '5/1/2012', @d2 = '11/30/2012'


SELECT ...
WHERE a.AccountID in (1,2,3,4,5) AND
ISNULL(b.ActivityDate, @d1) BETWEEN @d1 and @d2
```

Comment: -1: Moving the join predicate into the WHERE clause makes the query act like an INNER JOIN rather than a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: (I'm not the down voter). I'd recommend against this approach as it uses an arbitrary hard-coded value inside the `ISNULL`. The value has no semantic meaning and is confusing to anyone reading the code later.

Comment: @Norla Have a look at the fiddle example that I have given above. Can you explain me what you mean??

Comment: @ean5533 I appreciate your comment. Arbitrary date was added as OP had them hardcoded as well. I have taken it off now anyway. thanks mate !. But the guy who down voted me has no value reason. I have added a fiddle to prove it works.

Comment: @Kaf Understandable, and your updated example looks reasonable to me. +1

Comment: @Kaf Changed my vote.  What you wrote works, but coalescing the values in the where clause seems hackish.  I'd argue that the predicate should always be defined in the join clause, rather than the where clause.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the following:

```
(b.ActivityDate is NULL or b.ActivityDate between '5/1/2012' and '11/30/2012' )
```

so that the original query becomes

```
 select
       a.AccountID,
       b.ChargeType,
       b.ActivityDate,
       b.Income
 From
       MasterTable as A
       left join
       TransactionTable as B on a.AccountID=b.AccountID
 where
       a.AccountID in ('1','2','3','4','5')
       and
       (b.ActivityDate is NULL or b.ActivityDate between '5/1/2012' and '11/30/2012' )
```

But the answer below is probably better.

Comment: @tcshain Use it in place of `b.ActivityDate between '5/1/2012' and '11/30/2012'`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below code:

```
SELECT
    A.AccountID,
    B.ChargeType,
    B.ActivityDate,
    B.Income
From MasterTable AS A
LEFT JOIN  TransactionTable AS B 
ON A.AccountID = B.AccountID
```

If you use  `B.ActivityDate BETWEEN '5/1/2012' AND '11/30/2012'` condition in your code, then it will not yield the results that you are expecting. Because for `AccountID = 1`, `ActivityDate` is `NULL`. So, record with  `AccountID = 1` will not satisfy your between condition.

Comment: You should stop making your spam answers and instead do more like this... but without including your website link. If you keep posting your links, you could find your whole account deleted - not just your spam posts.